# Randomize some elements inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, random

Hi I have a set or array:

```
$arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];
shuffle($arr);
```

this will return the randomized order of the array. but how can I code if the `'3','4'` and `'8','9','0'` must together? I mean the other value can go random order but these `'3','4'` and `'8','9','0'` must join together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to get those ordered elements first (another copy), then shuffle the original, then remerge them again with union:

```
$arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];
$arr2 = array_filter($arr, function($e){ // get those elements you want preversed
    return in_array($e, [3, 4, 8, 9, 0]);
});
shuffle($arr); // shuffle the original
$ordered = $arr2 + $arr; // use union instead of array merge
ksort($ordered); // sort it by key

print_r($ordered);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OwBudJ)

Comment: ngayun ko lng na notice, Hokage Du30 ikaw ba yan?

Answer (score 1):

Many possible solutions, one example

```
<?php
$arr = ['1','2',['3','4'],'5','6','7',['8','9','0']];
shuffle($arr);
// and then flatten the array  ..somehow, e.g.
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($e) { echo $e, ' '; });
```